# Print some db date into a html table in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've to print some data from my wp site db into a html table but I've some problem.
The PHP script is the following:

```
<?php
  global $wpdb;
  $query = "SELECT * FROM dailycoppergg ORDER BY ddmmyy DESC LIMIT 5";
  $rows = $wpdb->get_results($query);
?> 
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Data</th>
    <th>LME $/ton</th> 
    <th>Change $/€</th>
    <th>€/ton</th>
    <th>LME £/ton</th>
    <th>Del Notiz €/ton</th>
    <th>GIRM €/ton</th>
    <th>SGM €/ton</th>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach ($rows as $key=>$value): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value['ddmmyy']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['lmedollton']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['changedolleuro']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['euroton']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['lmesterton']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['delnotiz']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['girm']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['sgm']; ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

I've print $value variable and its content is the following:

```
object(stdClass)#12129 (9) { ["id"]=> string(4) "1071" ["ddmmyy"]=> string(10) "2016-11-28" ["lmedollton"]=> NULL ["changedolleuro"]=> string(6) "5605.9" ["euroton"]=> string(6) "5935.5" ["lmesterton"]=> string(6) "5693.8" ["delnotiz"]=> string(6) "5750.7" ["girm"]=> string(4) "5807" ["sgm"]=> string(6) "4789.4" }
```

The result is that tabel rows are empty and there are header colums only.
How can I print fields values into table columns?
Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

Okay I think this is because your $value variable is a object not an array. The correct get syntax for an object is obj->attr_name

Per your example

```
$value->sgm
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$value->ddmmyy
```

instead of

```
$value['ddmmyy']
```

$value may be an object not an array